# Remove border of tiles while Smooth the image by convolving with the boxcar kernel in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to remove the black border of each tiles in Google Earth Engine while doing "Smooth the image by convolving with the boxcar kernel" on sentinel 2.

Here's my code https://code.earthengine.google.com/155b6b5e2a3429d198f33429b2ff6349

I am not sure what i am missing there, can someone please help me

```js
// Load and display an image.
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2018-09-01','2018-09-20');
Map.setCenter(-121.9785, 37.8694, 11);
//Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 5000}, 'input image');

// Define a boxcar or low-pass kernel.
var boxcar = ee.Kernel.square({
  radius: 7, units: 'pixels', normalize: true
});

// Smooth the image by convolving with the boxcar kernel.
var smooth = function(img){ 
  return img.convolve(boxcar);
}
Map.addLayer(image.map(smooth), {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max: 5000, format: 'png'}, 'smoothed');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to apply a boxcar convolution on the sentinel-2 image-collection without creating the black borders that you see in your current results.

The variable you create on your first line, called 'image', is actually not an image, but an image-collection.

Those borders appear because you are applying the convolution to each image in that collection individually. So when smoothing, the boxcar can't use the information from neighboring images.

Furthermore, 'image.map(smooth)' also gives an image-collection, when you add an image-collection to the Map, GEE automatically reduces the collection to a single image using '.mosaic()'.

So a way to apply the smoothing without creating the black borders, is by first creating one image from all the different Sentinel-2-scenes in your image-collection and then applying the convolution (https://code.earthengine.google.com/0a94228bc281c53f9af1bbc0e077e118):

```
// Load and display an image.
var imag_col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2018-09-01','2018-09-20');

Map.setCenter(-121.9785, 37.8694, 11);

// Define a boxcar or low-pass kernel.
var boxcar = ee.Kernel.square({
  radius: 7, units: 'pixels', normalize: true
});

var image = imag_col.mosaic();
var convoluted_image = image.convolve(boxcar);

Map.addLayer(convoluted_image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max: 5000}, 'smoothed');
```